# How to disable overly generic forwarding constructor in c++17 and defer to copy constructor

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-constructor, perfect-forwarding, stdarray

If I have the simple class written using c++20 concepts

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, int N>
struct MyVec {
    std::array<T, N> m_vec;

    template <typename... Q>
    MyVec(Q&&... args) 
    requires (std::is_same_v<Q,T> && ...): 
    m_vec{std::forward<Q>(args)...} {}
};
```

and an example of it being used

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    using V = MyVec<double, 2>;
    V v0(1., 2.);
    V v1(1., 2.);

    V v2 = v0;
}
```

The requires statement prevents the copy constructor from being hidden by the overly generic forwarding constructor. See https://godbolt.org/z/8Me19v7Ks

If you delete the requires statement then the line `V v2 = v0` will fail to compile.

However I can't use concepts because this needs to be in a c++17 only context. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to use enable_if to protect the constructor. I could mark the construct as explicit but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Don't you also want that `sizeof...(Q) == N`?

Comment: Is it like a small non-related example? Otherwise why so complicated? `using V = std::array<double, 2>` in your `main` would suffice

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik New here? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Jarod42 the extra constraint might be a good idea though it would fail correctly fairly early on anyway and does not cause a problem for the other default constructors.

Comment: would be nice to have a "minimal-viable" example, because there's also a trend about asking "XY questions"

Comment: What are you going on about? The example is minimal and viable. It has a working example on godbolt. Exactly how this integrates into my million line long code base is not interesting to anybody.

Comment: that is why I'm asking whether it is a "small non-related example". Because if it isn't, there's no need in overbloating your code base with useless wrappers. https://godbolt.org/z/ncWsqfvGj

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik That was answered by holt already about 5 hours ago but thanks for the contribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `enable_if` to disable the template:

```
template <class T, int N>
struct MyVec {
    std::array<T, N> m_vec;

    template <typename... Q,
        std::enable_if_t<(std::is_convertible_v<Q, T> && ...), int> = 0>
    MyVec(Q&&... args) 
    : m_vec{std::forward<Q>(args)...} {}
};
```

---

I am not an expert with concepts, but most (all?) of what you can do with `requires` or similar, you can achieve with `enable_if`, although it's usually a bit uglier (and error prone) and will lead to much less readable errors from compilers.

Comment: That works. https://godbolt.org/z/5K438vEdM I've been using concepts so much the last 6 months I forgot how to do it old skool.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative I like about `std::array` wrapper is:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t>
using always_t = T;

template <class T, class Seq>
struct MyVecImpl;

template <class T, std::size_t... Is>
struct MyVecImpl<T, std::index_sequence<Is...>>
{
    std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> m_vec;

    MyVecImpl(always_t<T, Is>... ts) : m_vec{std::move(ts)...}{}
};

template <class T, int N>
using MyVec = MyVecImpl<T, std::make_index_sequence<N>>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nThbse5hE)

that doesn't requires SFINAE/concepts.

Comment: That is interesting. Why does this work? In that, how does this generate a parameter pack on *ts*. For example this doesn't work https://godbolt.org/z/6j967n4Tj I had always assumed that to generate a parameter pack one needs a template on the actual method.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing `T` is not a parameter pack, so you cannot use `T...` whereas `Is` is, so you can use `Is...` and thus `always_t<T, Is>... `. Note that in this case you'd need both the `&&` and `const&` version if you want to achieve what you already have since you cannot use perfect forwarding with `always_t<T, Is>... `.